# New to Python, GMail SMTP error

Tags: python, smtp, gmail, smtplib

I am writing a simple sendmail function to myself and I keep getting this error:

NameError: name 'SMTPException' is not defined

What is wrong with my code? Any suggestions?

```
import smtplib

sender = "user@gmail.com"
receiver = ["user@gmail.com"]
message = "Hello!"

try:
    session = smptlib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    session.ehlo()
    session.starttls()
    session.ehlo()
    session.login(sender,'password')
    session.sendmail(sender,receiver,message)
    session.quit()
except SMTPException:
    print('Error')
```

Comment: smptlib -> smtplib

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Python, you will need to fully qualify the name by prefixing it with its module:

```
except smtplib.SMTPException:
```

This is true unless you specifically import the unqualified name (but I wouldn't recommend doing this for your program, just showing what's possible):

```
from smtplib import SMTPException
```

Comment: Not to worry, even after 20 years working with SMTP, I still do that.

Answer (score 1):

That misspelling occurred many times to me as well! One way to circumvent this "problem", is to use [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail).

Jokes aside, I recently created yagmail to make it easier to send emails.

For example:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP('user@gmail.com', 'password')
yag.send(contents = "Hello!")
```

It uses several shortenings here, for example when `To` is not defined, it will send a mail to the same email who registered on the server. Also the port and host are the default, which makes it very concise.

In fact, since it seems you want to close the connection immediately, you can even use this one-liner:

```
yagmail.SMTP('user@gmail.com', 'password').send(contents = "Hello!")
```

For security, you can keep your password in the `keyring` (see documentation) such that you do not have to keep your personal password in your scripts, very important! It'll even save you more precious screen-estate.

Going all-in with the package (`@gmail.com` is default), you can get away with the following:

```
yagmail.SMTP('user').send('', 'Hello!')
```

Good luck.

Comment: @sureshvv Thanks :) Hope it serves you well.

Answer (score -1):

### from smtplib import SMTPExeption

---

exep smtplib.SMTPExeption

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).