# python - send email locally through smtplib error

Tags: python, error-handling, smtplib

I'm trying to send an email using smtplib without storing smtp credentials locally.  I found this article https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm but get an error.  I've fairly new with smtplib.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib

message = """From: From Person <from@fromdomain.com>
To: To Person <to@todomain.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: SMTP HTML e-mail test

This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format

<b>This is HTML message.</b>
<h1>This is headline.</h1>
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print "Successfully sent email"
except SMTPException:
   print "Error: unable to send email"
```

error

```
NameError: name 'SMTPException' is not defined
```

Comment: this should do the job:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115724/new-to-python-gmail-smtp-error

Answer (score 1):

`SMTPException` is in the module smtplib.  So you either need to import that name, or use `smtplib.SMTPException`

Answer (score 0):

u should do that smtplib.SMTPException
or  do this line of the code to import it  from smtplib import SMTPException

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).